# what is the unix equivalent to windows command route add

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

I need to run the command

```
route add -p 123.45.67.8 mask 255.255.255.0 208.00.000.000
```

on a linux server.  what is the unix equivalent?

Comment: `route --help` or `man route` would have displayed help to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

They are very similar.

To add a route for a network – in this example,
192.168.20.0 mask 255.255.255.0

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.20.0/24 gw 10.0.0.1
```

or

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.1
```

To add a route for a host

```
sudo route add -host 192.168.20.20 gw 10.0.0.1
```

If you run `route add` with no options it will give you the list of options that you can use. e.g., metrics, interface, and some others.

Also the man page will help.

Comment: `ip route` is the more modern tool, so I'd be inclined to recommend that over `route`.  I suspect we'll gradually see less of the latter over time.

Answer (score 0):

Without an explanation of what that Windows command does, it's hard to answer, but it looks like you should read the manual page for `ip-route`.

Comment: I need to run the command **on a linux server**. No windows involved.

Comment: Yes, but for a Linux user like myself, just presenting a Windows command with no explanation isn't very meaningful.

Comment: True. It looked like a linix command to me though, so I guess it is all up to experience with older commands (I mainly used Linux in the time there was no ip command yet and the 1.2.8 kernal was *the* stable one ) And I also needed to read the question twice to check no windows was involved.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the route be persistent is to add it every time the machine is started. This has same result as `-p` flag on Windows.

This can be done using `Cron`:

```
@reboot /sbin/route add -net 123.45.67.8 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 208.0.0.0
```

`dev eth0` can be used at the end of command if there is need to specify port to be used.

This works at least on Ubuntu 14.04 and probably on most modern implimentations of Cron.

Comment: Alternative to using a `crontab` entry is to specify it in `/etc/network/interfaces` (for Debian, I'm not sure which other distributions have it in the same place).  I'll write a short answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

To add the route every time the interface is brought up, and remove it every time it goes down, a suitable command can be added to the interface's stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces` (for Debian).  Here's one of mine (this makes local broadcasts go to the local network rather than to the ISP on my NAT gateway):

```
iface eth1 inet static
      address 192.168.0.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      pre-up iptables-restore </etc/iptables.rules
      up route add 255.255.255.255 eth1
      down route del 255.255.255.255
```

This can be easily adapted to your OS and needs.